# how to move focus out of text box in c# asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, autopostback

I have search box that take username and search on it in the userlist 
the problem is that I want from the program to search directly as he get first letter from the user

**Front-End**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" 
             class="form-control table-search-input"  
             ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"  
             AutoPostBack="True"  
             runat="server"  >
```

**Back-End**

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    int bb=TextBox1.Text.Length;
    adminuserlist2 = adminuserlist2.Where(o => o.AdminUserName.Substring(0,bb) == TextBox1.Text).ToList();

    if (adminuserlist2 != null)
    {

        Table1.Rows.Clear();
        Table1.BorderWidth = 1;
        Table1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Groove;

        Table1.GridLines = GridLines.Both;

        TableCell un = new TableCell();
        un.Text = "UserName";
        TableCell pass = new TableCell();
        pass.Text = "Password";
        TableCell email = new TableCell();
        email.Text = "Email";
        TableCell isactives = new TableCell();
        isactives.Text = "IsActive";
        TableCell typename = new TableCell();
        typename.Text = "Type Name";
        TableCell typeid = new TableCell();
        typeid.Text = "Type Id";

        row = new TableRow();
        row.Width = new Unit("120%");
        row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        row.ControlStyle.Font.Size = 25;
        row.ControlStyle.Font.Bold = true;
        row.ControlStyle.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;


        row.Controls.Add(un);
        row.Controls.Add(pass);
        row.Controls.Add(email);
        row.Controls.Add(isactives);
        row.Controls.Add(typename);
        row.Controls.Add(typeid);
        Table1.Controls.Add(row);
        row.ControlStyle.Width = 300;
        row.ControlStyle.Height = 30;
        Table1.Width = 500;

        Table1.ControlStyle.Width = 1000;
        Table1.Height = 500;

        Table1.CellSpacing = 50;
        Table1.CellPadding = 50;

        for (int i = 0; i < adminuserlist2.Count; i++)
        {
            TableCell un2 = new TableCell();
            un2.Text = adminuserlist2[i].AdminUserName;
            TableCell pass2 = new TableCell();
            pass2.Text = adminuserlist2[i].AdminUserPassword;
            TableCell email2 = new TableCell();
            email2.Text = adminuserlist2[i].AdminUserEmail;
            TableCell isactives2 = new TableCell();
            isactives2.Text = adminuserlist2[i].IsActive.ToString();
            TableCell typename2 = new TableCell();
            typename2.Text = adminuserlist2[i].AdminUserType;
            TableCell typeid2 = new TableCell();
            typeid2.Text = adminuserlist2[i].AdminUserTypeID.ToString();
            row = new TableRow();
            row.Controls.Add(un2);
            row.Controls.Add(pass2);
            row.Controls.Add(email2);
            row.Controls.Add(isactives2);
            row.Controls.Add(typename2);
            row.Controls.Add(typeid2);
            Table1.Controls.Add(row);
        }
    }

}
```

I faced a problem that I should click out of the text box to search
please any one can help

Comment: for this you can use ajax call .

Comment: You can [visit this link](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) other wise you need to use jquery plugins.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you go for `OnKeyPress` Event instead of `TextChanged` just change the event and it will be working

### **Front End**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" 
             class="form-control table-search-input"  
             onkeypress="__doPostBack(this.name,'OnKeyPress');" 
             AutoPostBack="True"  
             runat="server"  >
```

### **BackEnd**

```
private void TextBox1_OnKeyPress(string ctrlName, string args){
    //your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.Net there is no real textchanged event, it will only fire if the textbox lost focus and if you have set autopostback to true.

What you can do is the Following:

Add A ScriptManager to your aspx page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"/>
```

Add an onkeypress clientside event to your textbox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" 
         class="form-control table-search-input"  
         ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"  
         AutoPostBack="True"  
         runat="server" onkeypress="CallMyPageMethod();" >
```

Call your PageMethod:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function CallMyPageMethod() {            
    PageMethods.MyPageMethod();
    }
```

Add a PageMethod to your code behind:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void MyPageMethod()
    {
        //add your textchanged event code here
    }
```